# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, python-3.9

I have a django project that I am trying to connect with a postgres database. However  when I try to run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` I get the following error:

```
(card_crate_venv) G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\website>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\website\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\website\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Ross Waston\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "G:\Shared drives\Card Crate\Software Development\card_crate_admin\card_crate_venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
```

**settings.py:**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'psycopg2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
]

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'development',
        'USER': 'superuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': '192.168.1.100',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**packages:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this does not work because I was using python 3.9 as a interpreter. In PyCharm, I created a new interpreter, setting the base interpreter as python 3.7 and reinstalled all my needed packages it worked as expected